# Installing with Client Profile Application doesn't show app in start programs menu

Tags: deployment, installation

I'm using [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656819.aspx) to install an application, but it doesn't put the applications in the start programs menu. I've been searching in the configuration of the Setup project but I can't find anything self explanatory enough, and I can't find it in google either. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click in the File System tab, click "Add Special Folder" and select "User's Start Menu", then you need to create a shortcut in the start menu folder (instead of actually adding the project output).